# How to convert IntStream into List<Character>?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an `IntStream` object that I have limited to 30 elements and I like to get a `List<Character>` from all the `int` elements in the stream.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey! But why `List<Character>`? Please post what you've tried already as well.

Comment: Why List<Character> in the title ? Share an example input/output please

Comment: why you need List<Character>, are all numbers in range [0-9] ?

Comment: The stream contains int representing Unicode code points (i.e. 1578, 1583, etc.) and i'd like to convert these into their respective Characters and later create a String object. Of course, I do not repudiate the fact that there might be better ways to create that String objects and I am open to ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may map each `int` to a `char` then collect into a list, this will result in a list of character given by their ASCII code

```
List<Character> r = IntStream.range(50, 80).mapToObj(a -> (char) a).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(r); // [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, :, ;, <, =, >, ?, @, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O]
```

Comment: Don't you want the OP to answer your question first?

Comment: You could even use a method reference for the cast if you want to be fancy `char.class::cast`.

Comment: @Zabuzard `char` is a primitive type but the `cast` method expects an `Object`. So `char.class::cast` never works on anything. When you replace it with `Character.class::cast` it would work for `Character` instances, but here, `a -> (char) a` is performing an `int` to `char` conversion before boxing. So even `Character.class::cast` would fail as it would box the `int` to `Integer` before attempting to cast it to `Character`. In other words, no, you can’t replace this cast with a method reference.

Comment: @Holger Fair enough. I supposed it would work as `char.class` is indeed a thing. But you are right.

Answer (score 2):

in this way you can do this action.

```
IntStream intStream = IntStream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9);
List<Character> characterList = intStream.mapToObj(i -> (char) i).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

for all streams you can do this via mapping each item to a character and collect them.

Answer (score 0):

also,

```
List<Character> collect = IntStream.range(0, 30)
                .mapToObj(a -> (char) a)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: how is this different from existing answer?

Comment: 1. Clubbing
2. The range. He mentioned only 30 elements though it's not clear, i presume 0 .. 30.

Comment: *I have an IntStream object that I have limited to 30 elements* .. so what was remaining was to map and collect and other answers do that as well.

Comment: @ parrotjack: Actually it was an infinite number of integers in the range of 0 to 0xffff that I truncated by applying IntStream.limit(30L). I actually had an old fashion implementation that produced List<Character> but I am back into Java coding after 17 years and I see many things have added to the language (i.e. Lambda) and I was trying to figure out how to do this in Lambda as Mr. Zerehpoush illustrated. Last night I came close to that but I could not figure out the casting part and all google searches failed to produce results.

Comment: Thank you all for your sample snippets. It clarified the ambiguity for me, I just have to find a good source of learning Lambda. The Oracle Java docs certainly not a good candidate.